# How can I expand and collapse table rows (all of them, not each one) while the newest row always stays visible in pure js?

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, expandable

I have an input field where i put data in.

that data goes to a table and creates a new row, with the data in it.

the newest row is always on the top.

I want the table to show only the newest row and hide all the rest (meaning showing only one row),
and when i mouseover it using an event listener I want it to expand and show all other rows that were hidden.
when I mouseout, I want the table to collapse again and show only the newest row while hiding all the rest.

how can i do that?
every time i try to fix this i just make it worst
right now i doesnt show new rows at all for some reason.

thanks in advance!

thats my code:

HTML:

```html
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    </table>
 
    <form>
      <label for="fName">Name</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" /><br />
      <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" />
    </form>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
table {
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px black;
}

.expand{
display: table-row !important;
}

 .collapse{ 
display: none;
}

 tr:not(:first-child){
display: none;
}
```

JS:

```js
"use strict";

let inputBox = document.querySelector("#fName");
let tBody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const table = document.querySelector('table');

function addRow() {

  let row = tBody.insertRow(0);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
  cell2.innerHTML = "text2";
  inputBox.value = " ";
  row.classList.add('tr');
  
}

tBody.classList.add('collapse');

document.querySelector("#submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addRow();
  });

  // collapst/expand event listeners:
  
  table.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    tBody.classList.remove('collapse');
    tBody.classList.add('expand');
  })

  table.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    tBody.classList.remove('expand');
    tBody.classList.add('collapse');
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your implementation needs a bit of adjustment. In **addRow()** function, ensure that the newly added row is displayed while others are hidden.

```
function addRow() {

  let row = tBody.insertRow(0);
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = inputBox.value;
  cell2.innerHTML = "text2";
  inputBox.value = " ";
  row.classList.add('tr');
  
/* here */
  tBody.classList.remove('expand');
  tBody.classList.add('collapse');
```

Also in css file modify the expand and collapse classes as follows:

```
/* This will hide all rows except the first one */
.collapse tr:not(:first-child) { 
  display: none;
}

/* This class will show all rows */
.expand tr {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! if i want to add transition to make it a smooth expand and collapse, where should i add the transition to?

Comment: You're welcome. You can't use display property with transitions, as in css, transitions work well with properties that have intermediate values, like opacity or height.